# How to access the data returned by IncludeTotalCount with IMobileServiceSyncTable?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Im using IMobileServiceSyncTable and would like to get the total count without having to retrieve all the rows in the local db. Here's my query:

```
var item = await itemTable
            .Where(i => !i.Deleted)
            .IncludeTotalCount()
            .Take(0)
            .ToEnumerableAsync();
```

from the other posts, i should be able to call item.TotalCount however that doesn't appear. replacing **ToEnumerableAsync()** with **ToListAsync()** just gives me Count which ofcourse will be 0 because i used **Take(0)**

Anyone know how to get the Total Count without actually retrieving all the items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Enumerable you get back, should be able to be cast to the IQueryResultEnumerable (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/master/sdk/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices/Table/Query/IQueryResultEnumerable.cs), which is where the TotalCount property is defined.

ToList also returns a list that that lets you do the above as well (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/e9b2a32063063ebd8889d08df8568d763543eb61/sdk/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices/Table/Sync/MobileServiceSyncTable.Generic.cs#L201)  So either method should be usable here.

Comment: I know this is rather an old question, but I just wanted to give the thumbs up to PhillipV's answer.   This worked for me: 

    var query = await recipesTable
        .Where(x => x.MyField == "Chocolate")
        .IncludeTotalCount()
        .Take(0)
        .ToEnumerableAsync();
    var queryResultEnumerable = query as IQueryResultEnumerable<Controller>;
    var totalCount = queryResultEnumerable.TotalCount;